# How would you say "I have been to Croatia numerous times." in Latin?

Tags: numbers, adverb

"*I've been to Croatia once.*" would, if I am not mistaken, be "*Fui in Croatia semel.*". "*I've been to Croatia two times.*" would be "*Fui in Croatia bis.*". "Semel" and "bis" are so-called adverbial numbers. But how would you say "*I've been to Croatia numerous times.*"? A literal translation from English would be "*Fui in Croatia numerosa tempora.*", but I guess that's not proper Latin. In Croatian, you would say "*Bio sam u Hrvatskoj mnogo puta.*", and that would literally translate as "*Fui in Croatia multae viae.*", but I am quite sure that's not proper Latin either.

Comment: The usual Latin adverb for "numerous times" is *saepe*, which in Croatian, if the Internet is not lying to me, is *često*.

Comment: There is also [**aliquotiens**](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0060:entry=aliquotiens)

Answer (score 4):

The phrase "non semel" means "more than once." I think it is the best expression to communicate an ambiguous but plural number of times.

Haec quoque, quae praebet lectum studiosa locumque / Crede mihi, mecum non semel illa fuit.

Ovid, *Ars Amatoria*, 3.663-664

Comment: Question is if *non semel* can mean not (even) once - i.e., never.

Comment: I like it! Could *nonnumquam* work too, here?

Comment: @d_e not as far as I know. I have seen non plus quam semel to mean “only once”

Comment: @Figulus I think nonnumquam would work

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel  I thought of *pluries*, which is attested, but not classically. Lewis and Short recommend using *saepius* or *identidem* rather than *pluries*, reminding me of SebastianKoppehel's note above about using *saepe*.

Answer (score -1):

I would use the adverb “numerōsē” for “numerous times”.

Comment: [*numerose*](https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=%23numerose%23) is quite rare and seems to be used mostly for rhythm, not frequency. Do you have any examples in mind that make you think this is the best suggestion?

Comment: The connotation of rhythm is listed under Roman numeral 2 (II) in Lewis and Short. The examples under Roman numeral 1 (I) seem closer to frequency. I liked numerōsē because it keeps the spirit of the original English sentence since the English word “numerous” derives from numerōsus, -a, -um (granted “saepe” is likely a better Latin word for “numerous times” as mentioned by someone else above).

Comment: I was actually referring to the occurrences of *numerose* (the adverb) in the link in my comment. It's worth noting that the L&S entry has a section at the end for the adverb, and none of the given meanings is "frequently."